# При попытке вывести данные из БД приложение падает

Tags: android, база-данных, android-cursor

2 текстовых поля вносятся в БД и вносятся они без проблем (проверял через  Device File Explorer). Но при попытке вынести их (пока что в toast), приложение падает. И падает прога именно после нажатия на кнопку, которая и должна вывести

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAddMA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_MA);
    btnGetDataDB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnt_get_data_DB);

    dataBase = new DataBase(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();


    //кнопка для перехода на след активити и добавления в базу
    btnAddMA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //кнопка для вывода данных из базы 
    btnGetDataDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(dataBase.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int getTitleDB = cursor.getColumnIndex(dataBase.KEY_TITLE);
                int getTextDB = cursor.getColumnIndex(dataBase.KEY_TEXT);

                do {
                    String value1 = getText(getTitleDB).toString();
                    String value2 = getText(getTextDB).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value1 + " " + value2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Не получилось", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.adapter, PID: 9185
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
    at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:565)
    at com.example.adapter.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Без лога ошибки и указания строки, на которой она возникает помочь вам сложно. Однако, судя по тому, что вы не привели этих данных у вас обычный NPE.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб лог добавил, Ошибка выводится именно после нажатия на кнопку получения данных

Comment: Вы не указали строку падения. Предположу, что это `String value1 = getText(getTitleDB).toString();`. Что вы думаете делает эта строка? Судя по ошибке она пытается в файле `res/values/strings.xml` найти строку. Вы явно не это хотите. Из БД данные надо иначе получать. Наверное вы имели в виду что-то такое: `String value1 = cursor.getText(getTitleDB).toString();`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Эти строки не верны? 
    int getTitleDB = cursor.getColumnIndex(dataBase.KEY_TITLE);
    String value1 = getText(getTitleDB).toString();

Comment: Эти, возможно, верны. Точно не скажу - так с базой не работал, но выглядят правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Не верны строки получения текста - метод `getText()` принадлежит активности и выдаёт текст из ресурсов, а текст из колонок базы нужно забирать методом курсора `getString()`:

```
String value1 = cursor.getString(getTitleDB);
String value2 = cursor.getString(getTextDB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в запросе курсора. Вместо `int getTitleDB = cursor.getColumnIndex(dataBase.KEY_TITLE);` я написал `String getTitleDB = cursor.getString(0);`